# How to write an excel file on user desktops using a Python program running on AWS

Tags: python, reactjs, node.js, django, amazon-web-services

We have an application, the UI of which is developed using React and is running on user’s laptops/desktops, and the backend is developed using Django and is running on AWS.
When we create an excel output of a dataframe, it is getting saved in ec2 instead of the user’s laptop, which is quite understandable.

But how do we create these output files on the individual user’s laptops, instead of ec2, since these users are not having direct access to AWS?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look into and use a [FileResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects). Remember that the backend of your app still needs to send a response to the client, but in this case a slightly different one from a standard json/html.